# Break string into specific data using delimiter and store in the array in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following text string

```
Liane Lanford$310.40$0.00$325.92 Ken Christenson$134.75$0.00$141.49 Melissa Jaramillo$951.78$0.00$999.37
```

I need to create an array so that i can insert the data into mysql database in the following format

[image]

I tried to do it using `explode` but stacked at `Ken Christenson` and `Melissa Jaramillo`. And complexity is there may be 3, 4 five or more customer instead of 3. How can i do this in php.

Comment: Could you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could split it with regex:

```
preg_match_all('/ ?([^\$]+)(\$[0-9\.,]+)(\$[0-9\.,]+)(\$[0-9\.,]+)/i',$str,$results);
```

the `$results` array would contain the full match at index 0, followed by name, subtotal, holdback, total:

```
[
  [
    "Liane Lanford$310.40$0.00$325.92",
    " Ken Christenson$134.75$0.00$141.49",
    " Melissa Jaramillo$951.78$0.00$999.37"
  ],
  [
    "Liane Lanford",
    "Ken Christenson",
    "Melissa Jaramillo"
  ],
  [
    "$310.40",
    "$134.75",
    "$951.78"
  ],
  [
    "$0.00",
    "$0.00",
    "$0.00"
  ],
  [
    "$325.92",
    "$141.49",
    "$999.37"
  ]
]
```

for the insert part (that you asked in the comments), try this:

try this instead:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($array[0]);$i++) {
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table(name,subtotal,holdback,total) VALUES ('" . $array[0][$i] . "','" . $array[1][$i] . "','" . $array[2][$i] . "','" . $array[3][$i] . "') ");
}
```

but keep in mind that the values should be checked & escaped. if any name contains an ' , the query will fail

Comment: Perfect. could store it to array and now trying to store that into database as `preg_match_all('/ ?([^\$]+)(\$[0-9\.]+)(\$[0-9\.]+)(\$[0-9\.]+)/i',$cus_block_string,$results);
echo "<pre>";
$array = array_slice($results,1);
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";


foreach ($array as $payment_type => $payment) {
 foreach ($array[payment_type] as $pay => $value) {
  
  
  mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table(name,subtotal,holdback,total) VALUES ('$pay[0]','$pay[1]','$pay[2]','$pay[3]') ");
 }
}`

I  think i am not doing it right. Can u please help? Thanks

Comment: `Kim Ward$541.30$0.00$611.67 Kim Ward$784.25$0.00$886.20 Kim Ward$1,807.45$0.00$2,042.42`
for this string it is truncating the last data showing first 2 Kim Ward only

Comment: it's because of the commas in the numbers - i updated my answer accordingly (the regex changed - update the line with the command `preg_match_all` in your code)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its perfect now